# How to turn on/off applications notifications in the command line?

Tags: system-settings, 21.10

On Ubuntu 21.10,

If you go to `Settings --> Applications --> Software Updater --> Notifications` You can toggle it On/Off.

[Notification Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dd39C.png)

Also,

Software & Updater set to `Never`

[Software Updater](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lc7ju.png)

Is there a way to toggle these settings in the command line? That when you update them it will also take effect on the UI? for example, if you toggle them in the cmd it should also update the UI.

I checked `gsetting`s and I can't seem to find these options. When I toggle them on and off and run `gsettings list-recursively` nothing really changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While gsettings is preferrable tool for such operations, I could not find this option too.
But alternate tool works: *dconf*.

Toggle notification for Software Updater off:

```
    dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/notifications/application/update-manager/enable false
```

Toggle notification back on:

```
    dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/notifications/application/update-manager/enable true
```

Changes are immediately displayed in the UI of Settings.